# Invalid username or password, errorCode:0 but I'm using correct credentials

Tags: login

When I try to log in to CP as admin with correct credentials I'm getting "Invalid username or password" error and the response contains `errorCode: 0` (I'm guessing CBaseUserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)

Weird part is that when I pull the same database to my local dev I can login using same credentials.

Only thing I can see in the logs is:

> Tried to restore session from a cookie, but the given login name does not match the given uid. UID: bd098373-8d73-4f6c-8326-9f5a2825f5a4 and loginName: Guest.

PHP can write into /craft/storage folder. I tried clearing out craft_session table, overridePhpSessionLocation => false and removing craft/storage/runtime/, nothing helped.

I'm using PHP7.1 and MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Do you have anything blocking/interfering with cookies being set in your browser?  Have you tried it from multiple browsers?

Comment: Tried it on latest Chrome and Firefox without any add-ons. In normal and private mode. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've solved the issue. PHP was trying to save the sessions into a non-existing directory.

To check the current session path, I've added `var_dump(session_save_path());` in Craft's `/public/index.php` (was set to `/var/lib/php-fpm/session`).

Fix was to update `session.save_path` setting in the php.ini to point to the right directory with correct permission.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Nice. This article may be of use to you as well, in your session spelunking. In general, I've found Redis to be a nicer solution for PHP session handling: [The Case of the Missing PHP Session](https://nystudio107.com/blog/the-case-of-the-missing-php-session)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, Redis is the next step, but I didn't want to introduce even more variables into the equation.